# Java ftp listNames() returns always null

Tags: java, ftp

EDIT 2: I solved, the problem was the = instead of == in if(loginState=true), and that password.getPassword().toString() don't work as I thought

EDIT: it seems that the problem is not with listNames(), because if I bypass JFrame and implement the ftp functions completely outside the JFrame (in the main), it works.

I'm trying to do a small ftp client, it connects and logs in successfully. But when I try to read the file names with listNames(), it returns a null array of strings, and I can't understand why. 
(I'm sure that there are files and directories inside the root of the server, filezilla connects without problems).

Thank you in advance for help.

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.FlowLayout; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClientConfig;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
    private JTextField address;
    private JTextField username;
    private JPasswordField password;
    private JButton submit;
    private JButton disconnect;
    private FTPClient ftp;
    private boolean loginState;
    public Frame(){
        super("simple ftp client");
        ftp=new FTPClient();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        address=new JTextField(10);
        username=new JTextField(10);
        password=new JPasswordField(10);
        address.setToolTipText("Address");
        username.setToolTipText("Username");
        password.setToolTipText("Password");
        submit=new JButton("Connect");
        disconnect=new JButton("Disconnect");
        add(address);
        add(username);
        add(password);
        add(submit);
        add(disconnect);
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try {
                    ftp.connect(address.getText());
                } catch (SocketException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(ftp.isConnected()){ 
                    System.out.println("Connected to "+address.getText());
                    try {
                        loginState=ftp.login(username.getText(), password.getPassword().toString());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(loginState=true){
                        System.out.println("SUCCESFULLY LOGGED IN!");
                        try {
                            String[] names=ftp.listNames();
                            if(names!=null){
                            for(String h : names){
                                System.out.println(h);
                            }
                            System.out.println("End files");
                            }
                            else System.out.println("NULL FILE");
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else System.out.println("NOT CONNECTED!");
                }
                else System.out.println("NOT CONNECTED");
            }
        });
        disconnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(ftp.isConnected())
                    try {
                        ftp.disconnect();
                        if(ftp.isConnected()) System.out.println("An error occured, didn't disconnect!");
                        else System.out.println("Disconnected!");
                    } catch (IOException e1){
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                else System.out.println("Already disconnected!");
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Frame app=new Frame();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setSize(500, 100);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what commons-net api are you using? Old 1.4 or newer 3.x?

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski the latest version: 3.4

Comment: I had the problem that the 1.4 version was not able to read files with a date of Feb. 29. 2016 (yesterday, leap day).

Comment: @UdoKlimaschewski I used 1.4 but I had problem with Odo dependencies, and I read that they were solved with newer versions, so I changed.
There are no files created/edited on Feb.29